# Finding value that corresponds to same location in another matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to get factor scores for each person. Factors are stored in the dataframe `factors` I need to get the average of the values in another dataframe called `data` of the values which correspond to `factors` and store it in a new column in `data`. I apologize for the terrible explanation. I hope my example will help, and I am happy to answer questions!

```
factors<-data.frame(c(NA,2,NA),c(NA,3,1))
colnames(factors)<-c("v1","v2")
row.names(factors)<-c("col1data","col2data","col3data")
factors

data<-data.frame(c(2,4,2),c(1,1,2),c(3,3,3))
colnames(data)<-c("col1data","col2data","col3data")
row.names(data)<-c("person1","person2","person3")
data
#in dataframe factors row col2data is present (i.e. not NA) under factor V1
#go into dataframe data for each person and make a new column called v1 that holds the value of col2data
#do this for factor v2 and average the values to come up with one number for each person. Final result
data<-data.frame(c(2,4,2),c(1,1,2),c(3,3,3),c(1,1,2),c(2,3,2.5))
colnames(data)<-c("col1data","col2data","col3data","v1","v2(avg col2 and col3)")
row.names(data)<-c("person1","person2","person3")
data
```

I will try to break it into steps (as I understand the process):

find row names in a column of dataframe `factors` that are not NA

match row names to dataframe `data` columns.

Sum matching row names in `data` and store in new variable called the column name of the column in `data` (eg `v1`) for each person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this taking the row means of the `data` limited to the appropriate columns:

```
cbind(data, apply(factors, 2, function(x) rowMeans(data[,!is.na(x),drop=FALSE])))
#         col1data col2data col3data v1  v2
# person1        2        1        3  1 2.0
# person2        4        1        3  1 2.0
# person3        2        2        3  2 2.5
```

Comment: `lapply` might be more appropriate, and you also get rid of the `drop=FALSE` by indexing as a list instead of a column - `cbind(data, lapply(factors, function(x) rowMeans(data[!is.na(x)])))`

Answer (score 0):

I placed the way you noted how you understand the process as comments in the code to see where each step in the process is performed.

```
factors<-data.frame(c(NA,2,NA),c(NA,3,1))
colnames(factors)<-c("v1","v2")
row.names(factors)<-c("col1data","col2data","col3data")
factors

data<-data.frame(c(2,4,2),c(1,1,2),c(3,3,3))
colnames(data)<-c("col1data","col2data","col3data")
row.names(data)<-c("person1","person2","person3")
data

#find row names in a column of dataframe factors that are not NA
not_na_rows_v1 <- rownames(factors)[!is.na(factors$v1)]
not_na_rows_v2 <- rownames(factors)[!is.na(factors$v2)]
not_na_rows_v1
not_na_rows_v2
#match row names to dataframe data columns.
#Sum matching row names in data and store in new variable called the column name of the column in data (eg v1) for each person
###*note*### apply(...,1 ,mean) takes the mean for each row (the "1" means by row, "2" would mean by column)
data[, 'v1'] <- data[, not_na_rows_v1]
data[, 'v2'] <- apply(data[, not_na_rows_v2], 1, mean)
data
```